# How does the area affect the integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ a open bounded set. For any $r>0$ consider the integral:
$$J_\Omega(r)=\int_{\Omega}\frac{|x^s|dx}{r^c+\sum_{i=1}^m|x^{p_i}|r^{d_i}},$$
where $s,p_i\in\mathbb{N}^n$ and $c,d_i\in\mathbb{N}$. (In fact, integrating other function may meet the same problem below). It's easy to show for any open bounded $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$ containing the origin, one has
$$J_\Omega(r)\asymp J_{\Omega'}(r)\asymp J_{(-1,1)^n}(r)\asymp J_{(0,1)^n}(r),$$
where $f\asymp g$ means $0<c_1f\leq g\leq c_2f$ when $r\rightarrow 0^+$.

**Problem:** For given open bounded set $\Omega$ such that $0\in\partial\overline{\Omega}$, does
$$J_{\Omega}(r)\asymp J_{(0,1)^n}(r)$$
hold?

**Hint and Attempt:** It's easy $J_\Omega(r)\leq C J_{(-1,1)^n}(r)$ but difficult in the converse. And for example:
$$J_{W}(r)=\int_{W}\frac{dxdy}{|x|+|y|+r}$$
where $W=\{(x,y)|x<y<2x,0<x<1\}$. Change the coordinate $(u,uw)=(x,y)$ one has
$$J_W(r)=\int_{(0,1)\times(1,2)}\frac{ududw}{u+wu+r}\asymp J_{(0,1)^n}(r)\asymp 1$$

Comment: sounds suspicious, did you check the domains between two touching (at origin) circles or parabolas?

Comment: If $W$ contain a triangle with a vertex being the origin, then the conclusion seems to be true for the special example above. But for other example it's difficult to calculate. I post this problem because the origrin is "the worst" point of the integral area. So I guess the order of $J(r)$ doesn't change.